# How to embed a video from an external source (TikTok) in a chrome extension?

Tags: iframe, google-chrome-extension, content-security-policy, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, tiktok

I am trying to simply display a TikTok video on a page inside a Chrome extension.
Random example of the code I included in my HTML file:

`<blockquote class="tiktok-embed" cite="https://www.tiktok.com/@sabri.62drsm/video/7192368102720539909" data-video-id="7192368102720539909" style="max-width: 605px;min-width: 325px;" > <section> <a target="_blank" title="@sabri.62drsm" href="https://www.tiktok.com/@sabri.62drsm?refer=embed">@sabri.62drsm</a> <p></p> <a target="_blank" title="♬ Originalton - Sabri ރ" href="https://www.tiktok.com/music/Originalton-7192368158199466757?refer=embed">♬ Originalton - Sabri ރ</a> </section> </blockquote> <script async src="https://www.tiktok.com/embed.js"></script>`

The following errors show up in the console:

`"`Refused to load the script 'https://www.tiktok.com/embed.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.`"`

And

`"`Refused to load the script 'https://www.tiktok.com/embed.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'wasm-unsafe-eval'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.`"`

Some text and a link to the user's account are indeed being fetched from the source, although nothing more.

ChatGPT instructed me to add the follow snippet to my manifest:
`"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://www.tiktok.com; object-src 'self'"`
Didn't work.

Comment: Did you tell ChatGPT that its code didn't work?

Comment: Yes. it didn't have much else to offer

Comment: You'll be able to do it in Chrome 110 and newer: declare [sandbox + CSP for tiktok.com](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/sandbox), then add an iframe to your extension that points to this html file. Inside this iframe you'll be able to embed the videos.

Comment: Hey @wOxxOm, thank you for your replay. I downloaded 110 beta and added to manifest: `"content_security_policy": {"sandbox": "sandbox allow-scripts; script-src 'self' https://tiktok.com"},"sandbox": {"pages"["index.html","assets/Static/tiktok.html"]`

Added this to index.html `<iframe src="assets/Static/tiktok.html" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>`

Tiktok.html includes the code from the beginning of my post. Unfortunately, I get now an error "This page has been blocked by Chrome" in the place of the iframe. Any ideas how to get it working?

Comment: Change seems to occur from `"sandbox": {"pages"["index.html"` as without it, I get the same output as I mentioned previously (some text snippets from the source but now video).

Comment: 1) Add `:` after `"pages"`, 2) Remove `sandbox allow-scripts;`

Comment: After having `sandbox allow-scripts;` removed and reloading the extension I get "Invalid value for 'content_security_policy.sandbox'. Could not load manifest".
Issue seems really persistent, got another suggestion? @wOxxOm Your help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Hmm, then don't remove it. The documentation adds it, so it must be necessary.

Comment: @wOxxOm In this case, I remain with the message "This page has been blocked by Chrome". Maybe you have another thought? There's not much info about that online

Comment: It's the correct solution and it should work, assuming you've fixed the `:` mistake. Make sure the html path is correct e.g. maybe it's different after compiling to the final extension's directory. Also try adding a slash e.g. src="/assets/...."